# Can be the number of uncaught exceptions be more than one?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

The introduction of `int uncaught_exceptions() noexcept;` in `C++17` instead of `bool uncaught_exception() noexcept;` begs the question whether it is possible to have more than one exception at the same time.

According to the [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception):

> Return value
>
> 2. The number of uncaught exception objects in the current thread.

I tried to imagine such a case when it would be more than one.

Having racked my brains, I came up with only one idea: `throw` something in a `destructor` of local variable, within the same `try` block.

Yet it wouldn't do.

First, it violates the rule imposed on `destructor`s forcing them to be `noexcept`. Second, it can be rectified by dint of `noexcept(false)`, yet it would just call `terminate` instead of winding up at the `catch` block.

So it does not do the trick.

Finally, throwing anything within the `catch` block itself would be of the common run, nothing unusual. Since once one enters the `catch` block, `uncaught_exceptions()` decrements and becomes zero.

So I question if it is possible to conjure up such a case where `uncaught_exceptions()` would return more than `1`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The hint is given on the site you link:

> Sometimes it's safe to throw an exception even while `std::uncaught_exception() == true`. For example, if [stack unwinding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw#Stack_unwinding) causes an object to be destructed, the destructor for that object could run code that throws an exception as long as the exception is caught by some catch block before escaping the destructor.

Using this as recipe: We throw an exception, in a destructor of an object that is destroyed during stack unwinding we throw another one that is immediately catched, but while it is in the air we look at the number of uncaught exceptions (can be done via another object's destructor, `tracker`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

struct tracker {
    ~tracker() {
        std::cout << std::uncaught_exceptions() << "\n";
    }
};

struct foo {
    ~foo() {
        try {
            tracker t;
            throw 123;
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout << std::uncaught_exceptions() << "\n";
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    try {
        foo f;
        throw 42;
    } catch(...) {}

}
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

The crucial point is that the second exception does not escape `foo`s destructor. And to see both we need to call `uncaught_exceptions` before the `catch` block in `foo`s destructor is entered. Thats why I used `tracker`. Once the `catch` block is entered it returns again `1`.

I wouldn't know how to observe `uncaught_exception == 2` without this double layer of stack-unwinding. Perhaps thats also a reason this was overlooked at first and only fixed in c++17. On the other hand, more layers could be added to have also `uncaught_exception > 2`.

Comment: Somehow, I overlooked this note in the wiki page. Thanks!

Comment: @unegare thats good. If you had read it, I wouldnt have learned something today :P

Comment: Having a destructor throw, particularly during stack unwinding, has been discouraged (or assumed away)  throughout most C++'s history (including before the first standard was ratified in 1998).    For example, the standard containers assume that destructors of elements (the objects contained by the containers) do not throw [with various justifications including performance impacts when resizing if containers had to cope with throwing destructors].  So throwing from a destructor (or a "double layer") was probably not considered as a serious use case for most of the history of C++.

Comment: @Peter "The crucial point is that the second exception does not escape foos destructor." no destructor in the code does throw. I am not "throwing from" a destructor. I am throwing inside a constructor and catching inside. This was always ok, afaik

Comment: @Peter if  `Foo`s destructor would throw (during stack-unwinding due to the 42 exception) then the code would terminate, but thats not what happens

Comment: @Peter actually not sure if your comment was critique or just usefull additional information. In any case it is welcome, but if its the former then I don't get it ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number   Yeah, yeah.   Code which requires a destructor to swallow an exception, or a function using exceptions as a glorified goto (e.g. the `throw` can `try` and `catch` are all in the same function) have also been deemed poor practice for most of the history of C++.    So the most common reason, historically, for a destructor to swallow an exception is that another destructor is throwing.  Destructors rarely need to construct objects as well.

Comment: @Peter exactly. Once you have a function call that somewhere internally throws **and** catches an exception, its only a tiny step towards the same situation as in my code. You only have to call this function in a destructor, destructor is executed during stack-unwinding, and there you go. For a short moment there is more than 1 uncaught exception. Btw it doesnt have to be poor practice of exceptions for control flow, but in the 1 call during which an exception is thrown and catched the throw and catch can be very distant, even in different libraries

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number why exactly 42? in the phrase 'during stack-unwinding due to the 42 exception)'

Comment: @unegare: There are two `throw`s in their code, one for `42`, one for `123`, they're just specifying which one is the one triggering the unwinding (the choice of `42` for one of the `throw`s is presumably just the usual Hitchhiker's Guide reference).

Comment: @unegare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy , a favourite number for many geeks.  Another fun number they could have picked for this example would be `22`, because they you'd have have a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22 - any time you throw in a destructor, there's always a catch :P  (Either a `catch` statement, or the plain English meaning of a "problem".)

Comment: @unegare because it refers to `throw 42;`. I could have used anything else. You can throw anything as exception. Good practice it is not, but I couldn't decide for a proper exception, and wanted to keep it simple and short

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number :DD